# Parsing unquoted JSON keys using org.json.simple in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON stored in a string.

```
String data = "{code: '0', distCode: '123'}";
```

I need to get the values of code, distCode. But when I try to parse it as below

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject Details = (JSONObject) parser.parse(data);
```

**Unexpected character (c) at position 2 exception is thrown.**

I am sure it is because of unquoted keys in the string. How to parse the string into an JSON object using org.json.simple library?

Comment: Make it look like this ```"{\"code\":\"'0\", \"distCode\": \"123\"}"```

Comment: I don't think you can; it's not valid JSON. You _might_ be able to do something tricky like using an embedded JavaScript engine to evaluate it as a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

Could not find way to achieve it using org.json.simple library. Finally done it using jackson libraries.

```
    String data = "{code: '0', distCode: '123'}";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES, true);                               
    mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
    Map<String, String> Shop_Details = mapper.readValue(data), Map.class);
```